# how to find shortest path in array to go from station No 2 to station No 6

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a database where the routes table contains only fromstationid and tostationid.

What I need to find is the **shortest** path to go from station **Number 2** to station **Number 6**.

Note: I can't make any changes to database

routes:

```
let routes = [
  { id:1, fromstationid: 1, tostationid: 2 },
  { id:2, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 1 },
  { id:3, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 3 },
  { id:4, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 2 },
  { id:5, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 4 },
  { id:6, fromstationid: 4, tostationid: 3 },
  { id:7, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 6 },
  { id:8, fromstationid: 6, tostationid: 3 },
  { id:9, fromstationid: 4, tostationid: 5 },
  { id:10, fromstationid: 5, tostationid: 4 },
  { id:11, fromstationid: 7, tostationid: 6 },
  { id:12, fromstationid: 6, tostationid: 7 }
]
```

If I need to go from station 2 to station 6,
the output should be:

```
[
  { id: 3, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 3 },
  { id: 7, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 6 }
]
```

I tried to calculate the shortest path:

```
    let originId = 2
    let destinationId = 6

    let visited = [];
    let inroute = []
    let stationtofind = originId
    
    for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        const st = routes[i];

        let f = routes.find(st2 => (st2.fromstationid === st.tostationid
                                    && st.fromstationid === stationtofind)
                                    && !(st2.tostationid in visited))
        visited.push(st.fromstationid)
        stationtofind = st.tostationid
        if (f) {
            inroute.push(f)
            if (f.tostationid === destinationId) {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(inroute);
```

But the output is this:

```
[
  { id: 1, fromstationid: 1, tostationid: 2 },
  { id: 3, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 3 },
  { id: 7, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 6 }
]
```

When it should have been this:

```
[
  { id: 3, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 3 },
  { id: 7, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 6 }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain why that's your expected output for going from station **1** to 6 ?

Comment: This looks like classic graph theory homework... Have you try looking at [BSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)?

Comment: @NickParsons this just an assignment i need to get the route then i'll calculate the price based on station count

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should solve the problem, using the DFS algorithm you can find the **shortest** path:

```js
let routes = [
  { id:1, fromstationid: 1, tostationid: 2 },
  { id:2, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 1 },
  { id:3, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 3 },
  { id:4, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 2 },
  { id:5, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 4 },
  { id:6, fromstationid: 4, tostationid: 3 },
  { id:7, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 6 },
  { id:8, fromstationid: 6, tostationid: 3 },
  { id:9, fromstationid: 4, tostationid: 5 },
  { id:10, fromstationid: 5, tostationid: 4 },
  { id:11, fromstationid: 7, tostationid: 6 },
  { id:12, fromstationid: 6, tostationid: 7 }
]

let originId = 2;
let destinationId = 6;

let visited = new Set();
visited.add(originId);
let shortestRoute = [];
DFS(originId, destinationId, [], visited);
console.log(shortestRoute);

function DFS(currStationID, destinationId, inroute, visited){
    
    if(currStationID === destinationId){
        if(shortestRoute.length === 0 || shortestRoute.length > inroute.length){
            shortestRoute = [...inroute];
        }
        return;
    }

    let nextStations = routes.map(st => (st.fromstationid === currStationID && !visited.has(st.tostationid)) ? st : undefined).filter(st => st !== undefined);

    for(let nextStation of nextStations){
        visited.add(nextStation.tostationid);
        DFS(nextStation.tostationid, destinationId, [...inroute, nextStation], visited);
        visited.delete(nextStation.tostationid);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you change relation 9 to `{ id:9, fromstationid: 4, tostationid: 6 },`, does your proposed procedure report the ***shortest** path*?

Comment: You are correct. I fixed the algorithm to find the **shortest** path.

Comment: Should use BFS instead.  This algorithm can take exponential time.

Comment: This is true @MattTimmermans, but minimizing the time complexity was not part of the question, so it still answer it in a clear way

Comment: Yes, and it makes sense for the OP to accept this answer, because his homework got done.  Anyone who finds this answer later, however, should understand that it isn't an acceptable way to solve a shortest-path problem in most real situations.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues in your code:

- The loop always starts at 0, and `routes[0]`, which cannot be right if the starting station is a dynamic input.
- The algorithm is *greedy* in the sense that it will content itself with finding *any* path to the target station -- there is no logic that ensures it is the shortest.

The algorithm that is most convenient for finding a *shortest* path (in a nonweighted graph) is by performing a breadth-first search (BFS). To efficiently look up which stations have direct routes from a given station, it is good to create an adjacency list for each station.

Here is an implementation:

```js
function createGraph(routes) {
     const adj = {};
     for (const route of routes) {
         (adj[route.fromstationid] ??= []).push(route);
         adj[route.tostationid] ??= [];
     }
     return adj;
}

function shortestPath(adj, originId, destinationId) {
    let frontier = [originId]; // list of nodes to be expanded
    const comeFrom = {}; // Key/key pairs representing a linked list 
    while (frontier.length) {
        if (frontier.includes(destinationId)) { // BINGO!
            // Convert linked list to path array
            const path = [];
            let id = destinationId;
            while (id !== originId) {
                path.push(comeFrom[id]);
                id = comeFrom[id].fromstationid;
            }
            return path.reverse();
        }
        // Expand frontier's nodes into a next frontier
        const nextFrontier = [];
        for (const id of frontier) {
            for (const route of adj[id]) {
                if (comeFrom[route.tostationid]) continue;
                comeFrom[route.tostationid] = route;
                nextFrontier.push(route.tostationid);
            }
        }
        frontier = nextFrontier;        
    }
    // If we get here, the destination is not reachable from the origin
}

// Example run
let routes = [
    { id:1, fromstationid: 1, tostationid: 2 },
    { id:2, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 1 },
    { id:3, fromstationid: 2, tostationid: 3 },
    { id:4, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 2 },
    { id:5, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 4 },
    { id:6, fromstationid: 4, tostationid: 3 },
    { id:7, fromstationid: 3, tostationid: 6 },
    { id:8, fromstationid: 6, tostationid: 3 },
    { id:9, fromstationid: 4, tostationid: 5 },
    { id:10, fromstationid: 5, tostationid: 4 },
    { id:11, fromstationid: 7, tostationid: 6 },
    { id:12, fromstationid: 6, tostationid: 7 }
];

const adj = createGraph(routes);
const path = shortestPath(adj, 2, 6);
console.log(path);
```